# prove $n(A \oplus B) =n(A) + n( B) - 2n(A \cap B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I can see the logic but can't put myself to see the reasoning. I don't know how to prove these type of questions, so so far I've been setting up an element $x$ contained in the left hand side and finding out if it is contained or not contained , in on a part the right hand side.

Comment: Well, what is $n$?

Comment: What about $\oplus$?

Comment: n is just the number of elements in a set. the crosshair symbol is just exclusive or I believe

Comment: n(A) is the size of A, and $\oplus$ is the symmetric difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the facts that $A \oplus B= A\cup B - A \cap B $, $N(A-B)=N(A)-N(A \cap B)$ and $N(A\cup B)=N(A)+N(B)-N(A \cap B) $.

Comment: Thanks, I figure you don't need the $N(A-B)$ part if you just subsitute.

Comment: You're welcome! I didn't understand your note, if for example, $A=\{1,2,3\} $ and $B=\{1,4\}$ then $n(A)-n(B)=1$ when $n(A-B)=2$, the reason you can just subsitute in the exercise cause by the trivial fact that $A\cap B  \subseteq A\cap B $.

Comment: Oh, i see that was an intersection not a union. my mistake